# IPC::Run timeout execute subroutine

Tags: perl, timeout, ipc

I have a perl script in which I am calling subroutine 'A' which executes the IPC::Run command with a set timeout value.

When the timeout happens, I get the following message: 
    IPC::Run: timeout on timer #5 at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/IPC/Run.pm line 2936

and my script returns back control from subroutine 'A' to the parent.

I want to modify this behavior such that when the timeout happens, a different subroutine 'B' gets invoked.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
eval { ... code using IPC::Run .. }
$@ and B()
```

Or you might look at the IPC::Run manpage and read the section about timeouts which comes with example code